# Pure CSS accordion stop anchor page scroll

Tags: html, accordion

I have a pure CSS accordion, it works great, but an issue is handling click shifting the screen up to the anchor tag;

```
<div class="collapse-content">
    <div class="collapse" id="instagram">
        <a class="instagram" href="#instagram" onClick="return false;"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>Insta</a>
        <div class="content">
        <div class="inner-content">
            Insta content
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="twitter">
        <a class="twitter" href="#twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>Twitter</a>
        <div class="content">
        <div class="inner-content">
            Twitter content
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="dribbble">
        <a class="dribbble" href="#dribbble"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i>Dribble</a>
        <div class="content">
        <div class="inner-content">
            Dribble content
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I suppress the browser scrolling the anchor to the top of the screen? I've tried adding a ? ! and 0 to the end of the anchor, but that breaks the link from working and as you can see above I've tried onClick="return false;" which stops the click. I'm guessing what I need is some sort of offset, as I don't want to suppress the click event just the scrolling too.

@ the moment I'm avoiding using Jquery, ideally no JS but trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure, but what you might need is to listen to the click event and call [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: Also, good choice on not using jquery. You don't need it in this case, and you don't need it ever.

Answer (score 0):

If these aren't links, then you shouldn't be using `<a>` tags. Links can:

- link to another document
- link to another part of the same document

In this case, clicking triggers an action, you should use a `<button type="button">` tag.